# Translation of devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for the user registration... and i want to translate it in French, I get the file traduction :

```
  fr:
    errors:
      messages:
        not_found: "n'a pas été trouvé(e)"
        already_confirmed: "a déjà été confirmé(e)"
        not_locked: "n'était pas verrouillé(e)"
        not_saved:
          one: "1 erreur a empéché ce %{resource} d'être sauvegardé:"
          other: "%{count} erreurs ont empéché ce %{resource} d'être sauvegardé:"
    devise:
      shared:
        sign_in: "Se connecter"
        sign_up: "S'enregistrer"
        forgot_password: "Mot de passe oublié ?"
        didnt_receive_confirmation_instructions?: "Vous n'avez pas reçu de courriel de confirmation ?"
        didnt_receive_unlock_instructions?: "Vous n'avez pas reçu de courriel de déverrouillage de votre compte ?"
        sign_in_with_omniauth: "Se connecter avec %{provider}"
        .....
        .....
```

And i write this on my config/application.rb :

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

I have reboot apache but nothing to do, i don't have any traduction on messages as "Sign In Successfull..."

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to add

```
 I18n.locale = :fr
```

If you have a problem with the production environnement, you can use :

```
config.before_configuration do
  I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.locale = :fr
  I18n.default_locale = :fr
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  config.i18n.locale = :fr
  # bypasses rails bug with i18n in production\
  I18n.reload!
  config.i18n.reload!
end

config.i18n.locale = :fr
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

In config/application.rb

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just did and it works:

1. copy devise.fr.yml to config/locales
2. add "config.i18n.default_locale = :fr" to config/application.rb
3. reboot mongrel